# Book involving a war with aliens, space travel, and time dilation

Tags: story-identification, books, military-sf

This is all I remember of the book:

- Humanity gets into a fight with aliens that have weird bodies. It  turns out by the end of the book that the aliens are all duplicates of the same alien.
- The book talks quite a few times about how, if you travel in space, time gets faster (or slower - I don't remember) and a woman goes on a ship and travels a couple of times until the main character finds her.
- The main character (a man) and a group of others (as soldiers) go and fight the aliens and, after he returns to Earth (I think 50 or 60  years have passed), he goes to his mother, who always has a bodyguard at that time.
- When he comes back to Earth for the second time (not sure), all people are pretty much gay, and a female makes a comment about how it's gross that men 'put their private part into women'.
- His group of soldiers fight the aliens even after the war between the aliens and humans ends, but when they find out, they go back.
- I am pretty sure the main character becomes an officer.

Sorry if this isn't enough information, but this is all I remember, as it was a couple years ago.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[The Forever War](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forever_War) by Joe Haldeman is what you're looking for. From the wiki article

> Mandella, with fellow soldier and lover Marygay Potter, returns to
> civilian life, only to find humanity drastically changed. He and the
> other discharged soldiers have difficulty fitting into a society that
> has altered almost beyond their comprehension. The veterans learn
> that, to curb overpopulation, which led to class wars around the world
> caused by inequitable rationing, **homosexuality has become officially
> encouraged by many of the world's nations.**

And

> Upon return, the strike force learns this is the last battle of the
> war. Humanity has begun to clone itself, resulting in a new,
> collective species calling itself simply Man. Man is able to
> communicate with the **Taurans, who are also clones.**

And finally

> Mandella travels to one of these colonies (named "Middle Finger" in
> the definitive version of the novel) where he is reunited with Potter,
> who had been discharged much earlier and **had taken trips in space to
> use time dilation to age at a much slower rate,** hoping for Mandella's
> return.

Comment: thanks so much didn't expect a response to fast, and yes it is the book, i was also surprised to see it was a book from 50 years ago i read it like 4 years ago, anyways thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. It's a famous book.  If you like my answer, click the checkmark

Answer (score 4):

This will be *[The Forever War](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21611.The_Forever_War)* by Joe Haldeman.

William Mandela is enlisted to fight the 'Taurans', and the novel covers a part of his training and a series of missions, including promotions after each one.

Interstellar travel is achieved through travelling through 'collapsars' which enable instantaneous travel, but the approach is at near-lightspeed leading to relativistic effects - years or centuries pass on Earth while he is travelling.

There are significant sociological changes between each trip. On the first  Earth is overcrowded with limited resources, so people (including his mother) have bodyguards.

On a later mission, homosexuality is the norm, to the extent that heterosexual relationships are considered abnormal (this reverses by the end of his final trip).

Due to the time dilation effects, after his final battle he returns to Earth to discover the war is over - humanity has evolved to a form of collective mind, which enabled them to communicate with the Taurans who were a hive mind from the beginning.